# "It is only me that is" or "It is only I that am"

Tags: clauses, emphasis

> It is only me that is confused.

or

> It is only I that am confused.

The first one sounds more natural to me while the second one appears to me as grammatically correct. Which one is correct?

Comment: I would certainly use *who* not *that*.

Comment: @tchrist. ‘With restrictive relative clauses, _that_ is a general-purpose relative pronoun. It occurs with animate and inanimate heads’(‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English').

Comment: @BarrieEngland Be that as it may, I would still use *who*.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Could you please answer this question for me? I'm really stuck on which one to use and need to use it right away.

Comment: How about "I am the only one who is confused."?

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's a great alternative. Thanks Andrew. I still wonder which one in my question is correct though.

Comment: They both are, although I'd also use *who* not *that*. And I would say the second is formal to the point of overdoing it. Barrie's answer is good -- "unexceptionable" is right; I wouldn't take exception to it, but I don't think I'd use that formal construction.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks again for your valuable input.

Comment: From what I've seen in literature and from the divergent answers here so far, both are correct, depending on whether you are writing for a general reader or for an examiner in grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is as much about what form of the first person singular personal pronoun should follow ‘It is . . .’ as it is about the form of the subsequent verb *be*.

The normal response to a question such as ‘Who’s there?’ is ‘It’s me.’ However, when, as here, the clause is modified by a relative clause, *I* loses the formality it has in the response ‘It is I’. Thus, ‘It is only I who am confused’ is unexceptionable. (I have substituted *who* for *that* to avoid clouding the issue over the choice between the two.)

The question remains whether ‘It is only’ can be followed by ‘me’, and, if so, whether *is* or *am* is the appropriate form of the verb. I think the answer to the first part is that it can be, and that the answer to the second part is that the most likely form of the verb is *is*. That seems to be because *me* doesn’t expect *am* in the way that *I* does. But use ‘It is only I  . . .’ and there is no further choice to be made.

Comment: But it ain't me, babe. No, no, no, it ain't me babe, it ain't me you're lookin' for. Babe. –Bob Dylan

Comment: @StoneyB. _Me_ is entirely appropriate in such an informal context.

Answer (score 3):

As in many of these cases, it really depends on what you mean by "grammatically correct".

As you point out, the first version would probably be judged as sounding more natural by most native speakers. So it is certainly grammatical or "correct" in that sense.

Now, irrespectively of what sounds natural, some speakers aesthetically prefer (or have been taught to aesthetically prefer) the second version, at least in formal writing. Subscribers to that rule would probably also use "who" rather than "that".

So, the second version is the "correct" version *if* you subscribe to a rule that artificially demands this form. But it's really up to you whether or not you decide to subscribe to that rule: it's just an artificial invention at the end of the day. (It's also worth noting, as with most prescriptive rules, that the argumentation behind it is essentially nonsense...)

Comment: +1 A good point that should have been put forth (argued for) much more strongly.